# datediff between multiple records in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have one scenario where i want to get a count if date difference between the two dates is
<=14 days.That is in first table i have to filter records where any one value of DATE1 values are <=14 days of DATE2.

```
For Ex:
 q1="SELECT DATE1 FROM DATE1_TABLE";
 q2="SELECT DATE2 FROM DATE2_TABLE";

 My simple query :

 SELECT 
    COUNT(*) 
 FROM 
     DATE1_TABLE WHERE DATEDIFF(DD,DATE1,(SELECT DATE2 FROM DATE2_TABLE))<=14
```

But i have multiple records in both the tables,but i want to choose any record having
this difference then it will get a count >0.So,it is throwing error subquery returned more
than one record.I want some solutions for this.I am using SQL SERVER 2008

NOTE:I can't use join here.because i wanted results from two different queries.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As you point out, the second table has many records on it. So which dates in the first table do you want to compare with which dates in the second - all of them, some of them, or what? How do you want to decide which records to compare with which?

Comment: Sorry for bad explanation.I am having 2 queries first query will give no of dates and second query will give a only one date.I need to check any date in  the first query <=14 of the date value of second query.Then it will return a count.Thanks

Comment: OK, you only want to pick one date from the second table, but *which one* - the smallest, the largest, the median, some other date ...?

Comment: i think i can use cte for the same...:) .. i will update soon

Answer (score 1):

You can use TOP 1 clause in your query..

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM DATE1_TABLE 
     WHERE DATEDIFF(DD,DATE1,(SELECT DATE2 FROM DATE2_TABLE))<=14
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use SELECT which will return multiple values where function expects scalar value... however you can join those tables:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT dt1.*)
FROM DATE1_TABLE dt1 INNER JOIN DATE2_TABLE dt2 ON DATEDIFF(DD,DATE1,DATE2)<=14
```

This query will join tables on values only when they are within 14 days and count on unique values from DATE1_TABLE. I have no idea if is it performance wise.

Comment: You *can* use a select if the select will only return one value.

Comment: "where function expects scalar value"